# Fixing "Warning: Illegal string offset" -- (but without losing content)

Tags: php, web-services, codeigniter, simplexml

> *I have searched for solution for this problem but none fix my problem. 
>   The answers suggest that I use `isset` to check the array before working on it. But I will explain how it doesnt do it for me later.*

**Pre-req:**

I've got a huge XML file from a tour & travel webservice which I would parse and convert to PHP array and later do some operation on it. (Filter tours mostly).

**My Approach:**
I'm using SimpleXML to load the xml and convert it to PHP array like so:

```
$xml = file_get_contents(APPPATH."tour.xml", true);
$xmlString = htmlentity_to_xml($xml); //custom method to clean XML
$Str = simplexml_load_string($xmlString, 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA);

//converting to array
$json = json_encode($Str);
$array = json_decode($json,TRUE);
```

Then I'm sending this array to a `fitlerTours($searchParams, $tourArray)` method along with search parameters (cityName & dates) and the array itself.

Then using `foreach()` i'm going through each tour to look for the cityName and raising a flag if found.

**The Problem**
When I filter the tours (the ones which contain cityName) for dates, I'm getting this.

```
Severity: Warning
Message: Illegal string offset 'year'
Filename: controllers/tourFilter.php
Line Number: 78
```

Warning shows for offeset 'month' and 'day' also. 
Here's my PHP for date filter: (Line 78 is 4th line)

```
if($flag == 1){
  if(!empty($fromDate)){
     foreach($tour['departureDates']['date'] AS $date){
        $dateDep = strtotime($date['year'] . "-" . (($date['month']) < 10 ? "0".$date['month'] : $date['month']) . "-" . (($date['day']) < 10 ? "0".$date['day'] : $date['day']));
        if(strtotime($fromDate) <= $dateDep && $dateDep <= strtotime($fromDate . "+".$range." days")){
          if($date['departureStatus'] != "SoldOut"){
             $dateFlag = 1;
          }
        }
     }
  }
  else{
     $dateFlag = 1;
  }
  $flag = 0;
}

if($dateFlag == 1){//Collect tours which contain the keyword & dates to $response array
   $responseArray[] = $tour;
   $dateFlag = false; //Reset Flag
}
```

Here's the snippet of XML:

```
...
<departureDates>
        <date>
            <day>7</day>
            <month>1</month>
            <year>2016</year>
            <singlesPrice>12761</singlesPrice>
            <doublesPrice>9990</doublesPrice>
            <triplesPrice>0</triplesPrice>
            <quadsPrice>0</quadsPrice>
            <shipName/>
            <departureStatus>Available</departureStatus>
        </date>
        <date>
            <day>8</day>
            <month>1</month>
            <year>2016</year>
            <singlesPrice>12761</singlesPrice>
            <doublesPrice>9990</doublesPrice>
            <triplesPrice>0</triplesPrice>
            <quadsPrice>0</quadsPrice>
            <shipName/>
            <departureStatus>SoldOut</departureStatus>
        </date>
</departureDates>
...
```

Now if i use the solution I found by searching around is check if the array is set properly by `isset()` it doesn't return true and line 78 is not executed and the data is lost. But I need the data.

This happens for only keywords i search.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to log the content of `$date` (`print_r($date,true)`) ? it may not be an array... It looks like the errors says it is a string...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error says that the `$date` var is detected as string in some point...

> Characters within strings may be accessed and modified by specifying
>   the zero-based offset of the desired character after the string using
>   square array brackets, as in $str[42]. Think of a string as an array
>   of characters for this purpose. 
>   [See here](https://php.net/en/language.types.string)

So try this:

```
    if(is_array($date)){
        $dateDep = strtotime($date['year'] . "-" . (($date['month']) < 10 ? "0".$date['month'] : $date['month']) . "-" . (($date['day']) < 10 ? "0".$date['day'] : $date['day']));
        if(strtotime($fromDate) <= $dateDep && $dateDep <= strtotime($fromDate . "+".$range." days")){
          if($date['departureStatus'] != "SoldOut"){
             $dateFlag = 1;
          }
        }
    }
    else {
        //If this is not an array what is it then?
        var_dump($date);
    }
```

Comment: Turns out there are 4-5 douchebag troll tours in that XML which have bad array structure... Thanks & Cheers!!